# I am getting this error " TypeError at /generate_pdf/10 expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not JpegImageFile"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to generate a pdf with content and uploaded images of each user uniquely in django but its throwing this error .[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0elL.jpg)

This is the code to generate pdf

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse , HttpResponseServerError
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import tempfile
import os
def generate_pdf(request, pid):
    # Get the user object based on the user_id
    user = Reports.objects.get(id=pid)

    # Create a new PDF object
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{user.Title}.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF using ReportLab
    pdf = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=(8.5*inch, 11*inch))

    # Open the uploaded image as an Image object
    try:
        image = Image.open(user.report_image)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
        return HttpResponseServerError("Error generating PDF")

    # Add the user's uploaded image to the PDF
    pdf.drawImage(image, 2*inch, 9.5*inch, width=3*inch, height=3*inch)

    # Add the user's content to the PDF
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
    pdf.drawString(2*inch, 8*inch, user.Content)

    # Save the PDF and return it
    pdf.save()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like the variable `user.report_image` is of type `JpegImageFile`, which is not compatible with the `Image.open()` method.

To solve this error, you can try converting the `JpegImageFile` object to a byte stream using the `BytesIO()` method from the `io` module, and then pass the byte stream to the `Image.open()` method.

Check this updated code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse , HttpResponseServerError
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import tempfile
import os

def generate_pdf(request, pid):
    # Get the user object based on the user_id
    user = Reports.objects.get(id=pid)

    # Create a new PDF object
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{user.Title}.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF using ReportLab
    pdf = canvas.Canvas(response, pagesize=(8.5*inch, 11*inch))

    # Open the uploaded image as an Image object
    try:
        image_bytes = BytesIO()
        user.report_image.save(image_bytes, 'JPEG')
        image = Image.open(image_bytes)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error opening image: {e}")
        return HttpResponseServerError("Error generating PDF")

    # Add the user's uploaded image to the PDF
    pdf.drawImage(image, 2*inch, 9.5*inch, width=3*inch, height=3*inch)

    # Add the user's content to the PDF
    pdf.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
    pdf.drawString(2*inch, 8*inch, user.Content)

    # Save the PDF and return it
    pdf.save()
    return response
```

Hopefully, this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I tried this and i am getting this error in cmd "error opening image: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format '
nternal Server Error: /generate_pdf/8"

Comment: Change this line of code user.report_image.save(image_bytes, format='JPEG')
 with this user.report_image.save(image_bytes, 'JPEG')